# Variable showing as both having a value and as being undefined in Chrome debugger?

Tags: javascript, variables, typescript, undefined, google-chrome-devtools

I have this Typescript function:

```
retrieve = () => {
        var url = "/api/Exam/Retrieve/" +
            this.configService.admin.examStatusId + "/" +
            this.configService.admin.examTypeId + "/" +
            this.userService.data.subjectId;
        this.home.retrieve(url)
    }
```

When I break on this line `this.home.retrieve(url)` and hover over examStatusId and examTypeId and subjectId I see the values 1,1 and 1.

When I hover over url I see `"/api/Exam/Retrieve/undefined/undefined/1"`

Here's my console output:

```
console.log(this.configService.admin.examStatusId)
1
undefined
console.log(url)
/api/Exam/Retrieve/undefined/undefined/1
undefined
```

Can someone explain why on the second line I see "1" and then below that "undefined" when doing a console.log and why the url has undefined?

**Problem solved:**

My Typescript had not compiled to Javascript correctly. I was debugging the Typescript but behind it was the old javascript !

Comment: I don't know what language the first code sample is in, but it's not JavaScript.

Comment: It is ES6 function shorthand: http://ariya.ofilabs.com/2013/02/es6-and-arrow-function.html

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. It's Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line is the return value of the `console.log` function, printed by the console for your convenience (and `undefined` because no value is returned). The first line is the actual output of `console.log`.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any idea why the url might be showing undefineds ?

Comment: Okay problem solved. My Typescript had not compiled to Javascript correctly after I made some changes. Thanks for the answer about the value returned.